# Need to add missing iteration id numbers to a series in text or excel. How to get this done without coding?

Tags: microsoft-excel, regex

I have a text, csv or excel file that looks like

```
||--ID-----||--Name--||--Date of birth--||
    1            Jo          1/1/11
    32           Mo          2/2/12
    3382         Ro          3/3/10
    21,252       Do          4/4/09
```

The real set contains 280,000 of these out of total of 1,000,000 rows. I need to somehow add all the missing ID numbers (which are all sequential +1 iteration) and just empty fields for name and dob. So that I get something that looks like:

```
||--ID-----||--Name--||--Date of birth--||
    1,           "Jo",     "1/1/11"
    2,           "",         ""
    3,           "",         ""
    4,           "",         ""
```

all the way to 32 then again till every integer is there. Is there an easy way to do this? without writing a block of code in a loop? Anything from Excel, some app, or any Windows text editor trick would be appreciated.

Edit: Please ignore the commas, quotes, etc.. The missing ID numbers is the only thing that's critical.

Comment: When you say text, does it still mean you can load it as a CSV file and Excel puts everything into cells (or not)? If so, then I think you want a Macro for this, which is potentially doable; I assume you have Excel 2013 as this is the only version of Excel that supports over 1 million rows (the limit is 1,048,576)

Comment: Sorry about the delay, but never did solve this. Yes 2013 is what I use. Didn't know about limit. I have a bit over 990k rows, lots of freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be:

1. import your CSV to excel as sheet 1.
2. on Sheet 2, build your complete list of ID numbers with a formula such as a2: =a1+1 then copied downward.
3. use vlookup formulas in the other 2 columns, referring back to your table on sheet 1.
   such as b2: `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:C13,2,false)` and c2: `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:C13,3,false)`, or to exactly match your request lets wrap that into an IFNA statement to return "" if there is no value. b2: `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:C13,2,FALSE),"")` and c2: `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A2:C13,3,FALSE),"")` (these formulas can now be copied down the column.)
4. Once populated save sheet 2 as CSV.

Note: for this to work correctly the table on sheet 1 will need to be sorted on column 1.  From the info given it appears to be that way, but if it's not sort the info on the first column.

With a million rows, this will actually get ulta slow on a lot of computers, I missed that before writing the formulas. I did something similar once with a large data set by turning off auto relcalc to get all the formulas in place, then did a manual recalc. which took hours but did correctly complete.

Comment: Thanks. Worked. Though it took 5 crashes, the fault lies elsewhere,  and not with your solution. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would resolve this with the Power Query Add-In.

I've built a prototype which you can view or download - its "Power Query demo - Add missing ID numbers to a series.xlsx" in my One Drive:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FA287BBC10EC562%21398

It takes a few steps to get there and a bit of coding in the Power Query language (M) to call the List.Numbers function (it's not exposed in the Power Query UI).  Still that's only one simple line of code - the rest of it can be built by clicking around in Power Query.

Basically my technique was to use List.Numbers to generate a table of ID numbers, then I added a Merge to get the columns from the input data (where the ID number exists).

The documentation for List.Numbers is here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/list-numbers-HA104111648.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA104122363

Huge "hat tip" to Matt Masson for the "Settings" technique.

http://www.mattmasson.com/2014/04/defining-configurable-settings-for-your-queries/

Note Power Query can read directly from a CSV file, which I would use as the source for the "Input Data" Query. It's probably easiest to delete that Query, then build a new one from the CSV file and name it as "Input Data". Uncheck the Load to worksheet option to save resources.